# Toggle .html()?

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to do a button that says View more before you press and then Hide when you have pressed. Problem is, when you press Hide it doesnt change back to View more. How do i solve this?

The jQuery code is:

```
   $("#single .vm").click(function () {
      $("#singlemore").slideToggle(150);
      $("#single .vm").html('Hide');
     });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to switch between the text `View more` and `Hide` and use `$(this)` instead of $("#single .vm")

```
 $("#single .vm").click(function () {
      $("#singlemore").slideToggle(150);
      $(this).html($(this).html() == 'Hide' ? 'View more' : 'Hide');
 });
```

Comment: you can also just use `this` :)

Comment: Thanks @wirey I missed that bit.

Comment: FYI, if you're deleting your old posts, editing out the content before doing so is pointless as anybody who's able to see deleted posts will also get to see their entire revision history anyway.